# Django вывод информации из MS SQL

Tags: django, sql-server

1. Имеется ряд таблиц на в базе данных на MS Sql Server 2012,которые изменяются пользователями, таблицы связанны между собой ключами.
2. Что имеется на данный момент, настроен postgresql сервер на Linux сервере, создана база данных для проекта django.

Ломаю голову над тем как отобразить данные с ms sql сервера в проекте django. Данные могут меняться только на стороне ms sql сервера. А django должен их правильно отображать в виде таблицы на сайте.

Comment: а причем тут постгрес если вы с ms sql сервером работаете?

Comment: с чем именно вы ломаете голову?

Comment: Как мне вывести данные из ms sql базы данных. То есть я создаю модель с необходимыми мне полями, как мне созданную таблицу заполнить данными, или может есть возможность взять данные sql запросом в django

Comment: Postgresql думал использовать как промежуточную бд между ms sql сервером и django

Comment: https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend

Comment: Благодарю,  я понимаю как подключить django к ms sql, ранее работал с pyodbc и извлекал данные из таблиц, но не совсем понимаю, как мне вывести данные из пользовательских таблиц.

Comment: Подключите ваше приложение к этой БД, воспользуйтесь командой `inspectdb` что бы создать модели, работайте с данными через ORM. В настройках приложения можно указать несколько баз, по дефолту поставьте постгрес, а в качестве доп базы - mssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. сконнектите django и mssql на readonly(права пользователя БД mssql сделайте readonly)
2. Выполните сканирование необходимых вам таблиц при помощи python manage.py inspectdb
3. Читайте ваши данные при помощи стандартного orm

Comment: всё получилось, данные получается извлекать из ms sql но, есть один вопрос, в получении данных из MS SQL применяются хранимые процедуры, я выполняю их чистым SQL запросом с использjванием raw(). Можно и как то соединить данные полученные raw() с данными полученными из таблицы обычным all()